# Automatically highlight "rest of day" in custom calendar

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an event scheduler in vanilla JS. I'm currently working on the ability to highlight a time-span by "dragging" the mouse over the desired times. I've got it working fairly well, but I want the rest of the day to highlight automatically if the user starts dragging on one day (e.g Monday) over to the next (e.g Tuesday).

In other words, if you start highlighting on Monday at 03 am and drag over to Tuesday 05 am, the highlighted area should automatically be Monday 03-07 and Tuesday 00-05.

I almost got it working, but all these coordinates and calculations makes me dizzy. Any help or guidance would be most welcome.

---

This is the snippet I'm having issues with:

```
if((j >= (startCol-1) && j <= (col-1) && i >= (startRow-1) && i < (row-1))) {
  rows[i].children[j].classList.add('selected');
} else if((j > (startCol-1)) && (j <= (col-1)) && (i < (startRow-1))) {
  rows[i].children[j].classList.add('selected');
} else if((j < (col-1) && (j >= (startCol-1)) && (i >= (row-1)))) {
  rows[i].children[j].classList.add('selected');
} else {
  rows[i].children[j].classList.remove('selected');
}
```

Here's a full snippet

```js
const table = document.querySelector('.table');
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
const sqSize = 28;
let selValue = 'p1';
let didMouseMove = false;
let startRow;
let startCol;

const cb = (e) => {
 didMouseMove = true;
 const x = e.clientX - table.offsetLeft;
 const y = e.clientY - table.offsetTop;
  const row = Math.round(y / sqSize);
  const col = Math.round(x / sqSize);

  for(let i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   for(let j=0; j < rows[i].children.length; j++) {
     if((j >= (startCol-1) && j <= (col-1) && i >= (startRow-1) && i < (row-1))) {
      rows[i].children[j].classList.add('selected');
      } else if((j > (startCol-1)) && (j <= (col-1)) && (i < (startRow-1))) {
       rows[i].children[j].classList.add('selected');
      } else if((j < (col-1) && (j >= (startCol-1)) && (i >= (row-1)))) {
       rows[i].children[j].classList.add('selected');
      } else {
       rows[i].children[j].classList.remove('selected');
      }
    }
  }
}

table.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  startRow = Math.round((e.clientY - table.offsetTop) / sqSize);
 startCol = Math.round((e.clientX - table.offsetLeft) / sqSize);
  table.addEventListener('mousemove', cb);
});
table.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
 const x = table.querySelectorAll('.selected');
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].className = selValue;
  }
 if(!didMouseMove && !e.target.classList.contains('row')) {
   e.target.classList.toggle(selValue);
  }
 didMouseMove = false;
  table.removeEventListener('mousemove', cb);
});
document.getElementById('sel').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
 selValue = e.target.value;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.head {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.head > div {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pre {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 32px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.pre > div {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  font-size: 0;
}

.row > div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.p1 {
  background: green;
}

.p2 {
  background: blue;
}

.p3 {
  background: orange;
}

.selected {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="sel">
     <option value="p1">Profile 1</option>
     <option value="p2">Profile 2</option>
     <option value="p3">Profile 3</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 
 <div class='wrapper'>
   <div class='head'>
     <div>Mon</div>
     <div>Tue</div>
     <div>Wed</div>
     <div>Thu</div>
     <div>Fri</div>
     <div>Sat</div>
     <div>Sun</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class='pre'>
       <div>00:00</div>
       <div>00:30</div>
       <div>01:00</div>
       <div>01:30</div>
       <div>02:00</div>
       <div>02:30</div>
       <div>03:00</div>
       <div>03:30</div>
       <div>04:00</div>
       <div>04:30</div>
       <div>05:00</div>
       <div>05:30</div>
       <div>06:00</div>
       <div>06:30</div>
       <div>07:00</div>
     </div>
     <div class='table'>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and jsfiddle fork: http://jsfiddle.net/a2v9rd50/1/

Comment: *Monday 03-07 and Tuesday 00-05* 03 for monday is 03 am and 05 for tuesday is 05 am. What are the 07 and 00?

Comment: @Cid, good question. It's meant to span across all 24h, but haven't done that yet (lots of divs to manually add, and that's not a problem I need to worry about right now).

Comment: *I want the rest of the day to highlight automatically if the user starts dragging on one day (e.g Monday) over to the next (e.g Tuesday).* It's working

Comment: @Cid, not very well. Try starting at monday 06 over to wednesday 01. You'll notice that the start time has shifted too.

Comment: I am very convinced that you should not rely on pixel positions, but instead detect what actual element is targeted on `mousedown` and `mouseup`.

Comment: @AndersTornblad, alright, but how does that help solve the rest of the algorithm? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this, that needs to be tweaked and refactored, but the selection "works".

I dynamically generated <strike>an ugly</strike> a stylished calendar. Each cell has an id built like this : `day_halfhour`. `day` being the x coordinate, `halfhour` being the y one. The cell for monday at 00:00 has id `0_0`. Sunday 23:30 has `6_47`.

There's 2 events listener on each cell.

One for selection starting (`mousedown`) that sets up the starting coordinates (day + hour) `startPoint` and raises the flag `selecting`

The other one is used for the selection (`mouseover`). It's executed only when the flag `selecting` is true. It sets the ending coordinate (day + hour) `coor` with the current cell id (`x_y`)

There's a 3rd event, on document (`mouseup`) that displays in console the starting and ending coordinates.

It's up to you to use that final event to design the selected dates and manage datas.

```js
function changeColor(x, y, state)
{
    let cell = document.getElementById(x + '_' + y);
    if (cell)
      cell.className = state;
}

let tbl = document.createElement('table');
let container = document.getElementById('myTable');
let startPoint = null;
let endPoint = null;
let selecting = false;
for (let i = 0; i < 48; ++i)
{
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
    {
        let td = document.createElement('td');
        td.setAttribute('id', j + "_" + i);
        td.innerHTML = "A";
        td.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) =>
        {
            let coortemp = e.srcElement.id.split('_');
            startPoint = [coortemp[0], coortemp[1]];
            selecting = true;
            changeColor(coortemp[0], coortemp[1], "selecting");
        });
        td.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) =>
        {
            if (selecting)
            {
                endPoint = e.srcElement.id.split('_');
                for (let x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
                {
                    for (let y = 0; y < 48; ++y)
                    {
                        //We're out of range concerning selection. background is white
                        if (x < startPoint[0]
                            || x > endPoint[0])
                            changeColor(x, y, "deselected");
                        else
                        {
                            //In the case where we're "painting" the first day
                            //of the selection.
                            if (x == startPoint[0])
                            {
                                /*
                                 * This checks if start and end are the same day.
                                 * to avoid "painting" too much hours
                                 * Or if days are differents, so we can "paint" until midnight
                                 */
                                if (y >= startPoint[1]
                                    && ((startPoint[0] == endPoint[0]
                                            && y <= endPoint[1])
                                        || startPoint[0] != endPoint[0]))
                                {
                                    changeColor(x, y, "selecting");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    changeColor(x, y, "deselected");
                                }
                            }
                            //last day of selection ...
                            else if (x == endPoint[0])
                            {
                                //... before or at last hour
                                if (y <= endPoint[1])
                                {
                                    changeColor(x, y, "selecting");
                                }                                    
                                else
                                {
                                    changeColor(x, y, "deselected");
                                }
                            }
                            //There, we're definitely in range and we can blindly "paint"
                            else
                            {
                                changeColor(x, y, "selecting");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
}
container.appendChild(tbl);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () =>
{
    if (selecting)
    {
        if (!endPoint)
            endPoint = startPoint;
        console.log('final selection : from day ' + startPoint[0] + ' half-hour * ' + startPoint[1] + ' to day ' + endPoint[0] + ' half-hour * ' + endPoint[1]);
        selecting = false;
        let days = document.getElementsByClassName("selecting");
        
        while (days.length)
          days[0].className = "selected";
    }
});
```

```css
.selecting
{
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

.deselected
{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.selected
{
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div id="myTable">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! I'll take a look at it more thoroughly tomorrow and see if this works.

Comment: I let you converting the coordinates into day and hours

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing can become really complex really fast.
I would recommend simplifying the code by using data-attributes in the HTML and splitting up the logic in reusable functions.

Here is some pseudo code showing how I would approach it.

```
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div data-date="2018-12-11T00:03:30"></div>
    <div data-date="2018-12-11T00:04:00"></div>
    <div data-date="2018-12-11T00:04:30"></div>
    <div data-date="2018-12-11T00:05:00"></div>
    <div data-date="2018-12-11T00:05:30"></div>
    <div data-date="2018-12-11T00:06:00"></div>
    <div data-date="2018-12-11T00:06:30"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
let mouseDown = false;
let selectionStart;
let selectionEnd;

const table = document.querySelector('.table');

const getElementValueFromMouse = event => {
  const element = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  return element.dataset.date;
};

table.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  mouseDown = true;
  selectionStart = getElementValueFromMouse(e);
});

const paintCurrentSelection = () => {
  const color = mouseDown ? 'selectionColor' : 'profileColor';

  // Find all the cells between selectionStart and selectionEnd ...

  // Revert the previous selection paint ...

  // Paint ...
};

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
  selectionEnd = getElementValueFromMouse(e);
  paintCurrentSelection();
});

table.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!mouseDown) {
    return;
  }

  selectionEnd = getElementValueFromMouse(e);
  paintCurrentSelection();
});
```